# How can share file to whatsapp?

Tags: java, android

I used the codes below. When I press the button, whatsapp opens, when I select the person I will share and press on it, the audio file is not sent and the text "sharing failed please try again" appears? Is there a problem with my codes, do not I understand the file format?

there is my raw folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bv2J.png)

```
 paylas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri catURI;
            catURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.app.package/" + R.raw.helikopter);

            Intent videoshare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            videoshare.setType("*/*");
            videoshare.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            videoshare.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            videoshare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,catURI);
            startActivity(videoshare);

           

        }
    });
```

Comment: You cannot share an audio.resource.

Comment: When I try to share it says the file format is not supported. voice
 how do i share on whatsapp

Comment: You cannot share an audio resource. Not to whatsapp. Not to any body.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you want to send a `.mp3` file. So you need the `setType("audio/*")`

I made an example with a ringtone. That's how you can send music:

```
paylas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/Soundboard/Ringtones/custom_ringtone.ogg";
          Uri catURI = Uri.parse(sharePath);
          Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          share.setType("audio/*");
          share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, catURI);
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
        }
    });
```

Make sure you have internet and External Storage granted in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Hope your question is answered now. Give it a shot, but I bet it works :)

Comment: still says sharing failed

Comment: Did you activate Internet with the required permission? I added this to my answer.

Comment: Should I save the mp3 file with external storage?

Comment: I did what you said, but this time it says "file format not supported" on whatsapp please help me :)